# How to deploy Applet with dependencies jar using maven and sign it?

Tags: maven-2, jar-signing

Can someone show me how pom file should look like to create a jar file with applet which depends from some other jars is it possible to have one jar as applet, and how to sign it?

Answer (score 10):

If you would like your classes **and** the dependencies to appear in **one jar file**, you should use either the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or the [one-jar plugin](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) before the [jarsigner](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/).  I have the following working setup with the assembly plugin, it will produce the normal (signed) jar and a ${artifactId}-${version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar (also signed).

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-my-applet-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>keystore</keystore>
                <alias>keyalias</alias>
                <storepass>storepass</storepass>
                <keypass>keypass</keypass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: The maven-shade-plugin is also an option for producing a single, executable JAR with all of the dependencies available on the classpath. The main difference is that the shade plugin includes all dependencies and embedded .class files as opposed to embedded JARs.

Comment: Any maven-assembly-plugin version bigger than 2.2-beta-5 will crash.

Answer (score 9):

This is sample pom for applet with dependency on other (signed) jar. Code of your applet module will be packaged into jar and signed using test key.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>0.1</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>applet</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>com.example.applet</name>
  <build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <keystore>src/main/keystore/signing-jar.keystore</keystore>
              <alias>applet</alias>
              <storepass>applet</storepass>
              <keypass>applet</keypass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>other</artifactId>
      <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is sample shell script to create key store (place and run it where your pom file is located):

```
#!/bin/sh
KEYSTORE=src/main/keystore/signing-jar.keystore
keytool -genkey -alias applet -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass applet -keypass applet -dname "CN=developer, OU=group 3, O=com.example, L=Somewhere, ST=Germany, C=DE"
keytool -selfcert -alias applet -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass applet -keypass applet
```

After mvn package you will have your signed com.example.applet-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. Place it together with your dependency (com.example.other-0.4.jar) in your web-application.