# Why do I get a NoClassDefFoundError in my applet, when using Apache Commons VFS?

Tags: java, applet, noclassdeffounderror

Can anyone help me make sense of this error message?
I wrote a drag and drop applet, which uploads via SFTP to a remote server. It works when I run the applet from my local computer, but once I put it online, I get the following error.

What is the reason, and what can I do?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/vfs/FileSystemException
    at com.zehon.sftp.SFTP.getSFTPClient(SFTP.java:20)
    at com.zehon.sftp.SFTP.sendFile(SFTP.java:50)
    at Combined.uploadFunction(Combined.java:103)
    at NewDrag.uploadButtonMouseClicked(NewDrag.java:187)
    at NewDrag.access$400(NewDrag.java:35)
    at NewDrag$5.mouseClicked(NewDrag.java:137)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you havent embedded commons-vfs as a dependency in your applet.

If you are using maven for building check [How to deploy Applet with dependencies jar using maven and sign it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027753/how-to-deploy-applet-with-dependencies-jar-using-maven-and-sign-it) for help on how to do it with maven.