# Managing keystore within jar file

Tags: maven, keystore, jarsigner

I have a maven project which needs to be signed.

To sign the jar file, I created an alias. This will be stored in my .keystore. Using the alias, I'm signing the jar, everytime a new version is created.

Is it possible to make the keystore to be independent of .keystore present in my home directory like storing keystore file in the Jar file itself ? If so, how to do it ?

What are the plugin details to be used in the pom to use jar signer plugin within the project ?

Comment: You want to put your secret key into the jar you are going to distribute?

Comment: The Jar file has an applet. Actually, I dont need to sign the jar. Since, my jar uses some other signed jar files, I have to do it now.

Comment: Found solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/2027753/691197